# Simple mesh generation using Fenics in c++, weird error?

Tags: c++, mesh

I am new to Fenics and I simply want to create a polygonal mesh with a hole in it. I have written:

```
// Vector of points
    std::vector<Point> pts;
    pts.push_back(Point(  0.0,   0.0));
    pts.push_back(Point(  4.0,   0.0));
    pts.push_back(Point(  4.0,   8.0));
    pts.push_back(Point(  0.0,   8.0));
    pts.push_back(Point(  0.0,   8.0 / 2 + 0.5));
    pts.push_back(Point(  1.0,   8.0 / 2 + 0.5));
    pts.push_back(Point(  2.0,   8.0 / 4      ));
    pts.push_back(Point(  1.0,   8.0 / 2 - 0.5));
    pts.push_back(Point(  0.0,   8.0 / 2 - 0.5));

    // Polygone
    mshr::Polygon polyline(pts);

    // Hole
    mshr::Circle circle(Point(2.0, 7.0), 0.3);

    // Difference: IT IS A SHARED POINTER
    auto difference = polyline - circle;

    // Create a simple mesh
    Mesh mesh;

    mshr::CSGCGALMeshGenerator2D generator;

    // Mesh it!
    generator.generate(*difference, mesh);
```

but I keep getting this error message and can't produce the executable:

> Scanning dependencies of target demo_poisson [ 50%] Building CXX
>   object CMakeFiles/demo_poisson.dir/main.cpp.o [100%] Linking CXX
>   executable demo_poisson CMakeFiles/demo_poisson.dir/main.cpp.o: In
>   function `mshr::CSGDifference::~CSGDifference()':
>   /home/fenics/local/include/mshr/CSGOperators.h:67: undefined reference
>   to`vtable for mshr::CSGDifference'
>   CMakeFiles/demo_poisson.dir/main.cpp.o: In function
>   `mshr::CSGOperator::~CSGOperator()':...............................

Anyone knows what is going on here? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: You can dry your code by using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back(Object(`

Comment: @kim366, thanks I did it, even though I do not know the difference :) The problem continues ..

Comment: Are you `using namespace dolfin` ? [`emplace_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) reconstructs the object passed as opposed to [copying it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)...  Aside from those things, have you tried explicitly calling `CSGDifference`?       `auto difference = CSGDifference(polyline, circle)`

Comment: Hi @Matt Perry , yes I am using "namespace dolfin". And just did auto difference = CSGDifference(polyline, circle) and got the following error message              <<error: ‘CSGDifference’ was not declared in this scope
  auto difference = CSGDifference(polyline, circle)  
                                                  ^
>>

Comment: @Noname oh, sorry about that- you should be referencing the correct namespace: `mshr::CSGDifference(polyline, circle)`

Comment: @MattPerry , no problems :) Now I am using <<auto difference = mshr::CSGDifference(polyline, circle) >>  and getting the error << no matching function for call to ‘mshr::CSGDifference::CSGDifference(mshr::Polygon&, mshr::Circle&)’
  auto difference = mshr::CSGDifference(polyline, circle)
                                                        ^
>>

Comment: @Noname have you looked at the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/benjamik/mshr/wiki/API/CSGDifference)?  The `CSGDifference` function takes two shared pointers of type `CSGeometry` as arguments.